# Копировать столбцы со сдвигом вправо Google\Spreadsheet php

Tags: phpspreadsheet, google-spreadsheet

Господа, помогите, не могу загуглить как мне скопировать нужные мне 5 столбцов со свдвигом вправо в Google\Spreadsheet на PHP?
Я хочу делать это многократно, т.е. у меня есть рабочий диапазон и каждый день, я хочу копировать его данные вправо, создавая там справа вчерашний день данных и так каждый день, чтобы данные за прошлые дни просто двигались вправо.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Если вставить на лист новые столбцы A:E (5 штук), то все остальные подвинутся вправо. В новые столбцы запишите свежие данные.  И так - многократно, хоть каждый день. В чем тут проблема? И причем тут PHP? Где Ваш код на PHP?

Comment: Александр, спасибо за ответ - а как ставить новые столбцы? Я умею только писать в существующие...

Comment: Например, методом [insertColumns](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertColumns(Integer,Integer)).  Но в Вашем случае могут быть особенности, связанные с PHP. Вы так и не ответили, почему PHP и где образец кода. А это может быть существенно для полного ответа на вопрос.